# Why does tsc (Typescript Compiler) ignore RxJS import?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, systemjs, jspm

I have setup my Angular2 project using JSPM and SystemJS. I try to import `RxJS` and a few operators in my `boot.ts` file but my import does NOT get transpiled into the `boot.js` output. So

```
// boot.ts
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'
...
```

as outlined here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS#es6-via-npm ends up as

```
// boot.js
System.register(['rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime', ...
```

`tsc` (tried with 1.7.5 and 1.8.0):

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es5"
  }

  , "exclude": [
    "jspm_packages",
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing???

**UPDATE**

TypeScript will only `emit` the import if it is used later in the code. I just needed the additional operators to listen to a `valueChanges` observable to an Angular2 `control`. However, the additional operators cannot be patched if the `Observable` class of `rxjs` is missing. So you kind of need to force TypeScript to `emit` the `System.register` for `Observable` by importing like this:

```
// boot.ts
import 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'
...
```

All credit goes to @RyanCavanaugh who pointed me into the right direction.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply `import 'rxjs/Observable'` did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from the comments, which successfully resolved the issue:

`import 'rxjs/Observable'`

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Observable class the right way:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Or the following if you want to include all operators in the same time:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make any difference. The issue was - as outlined in the wiki - that I did not use `Observable` later in my code, because I was just applying the operators to a `valueChanges` observable of an Angular control. Thanks for your answer anyway.